# How request for payment process work on Elance in hourly based job?

Tags: freelance-websites, hourly

Suppose if someone is working on a client project, in which they give support for a product, like bug fixing & updating the project.  This person is working on an hour-based rate, in which client finalized that the work will be 10 hours in a week for the next 2 years.

It is okay, once the person has completed four hours work that the client release the funds?

But suppose, in a month, there wasn't any bugs or maintenance. Should the freelancer still get paid for the four hours of work that person didn't do?

Comment: In elance you have facility to generate miscellaneous invoice.

Comment: Hi Williams, welcome to Freelancing.SE! It's a little difficult understanding what you're asking here, and this question is at risk of being put on hold. Can you please [edit] to give some more details as to your problem? If you need help with formatting the question, feel free to ask on [chat] or [meta]. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He should get paid for the 4 hours work he did.

The 10 hours a week probably means UP TO 10 hours a week, not definitely 10 hours every week.

So if he works 4 hours 1 week and 0 hours the next week, he should get paid for the 4 hours the first week, and get paid nothing for the second week.  The third hour he may have more work to do or not, depending on what the client asks him to do.  He should get paid for whatever hours he works up to 10 hours.  He should never work more than 10 hours in one week unless he clears that with the client first.

Comment: Yep, you are allowed to work up to 10 hours and you must be payed for any amount you do in a week, even if it is half an hour.

Comment: Hey Williams, and Emily, I put the question on hold because it's not 100% clear to everyone exactly what's being asked. We put posts on hold to give us time to improve them via suggested edits and asking clarifying questions in the comments. Emily, since you answered this, would you be willing to give the question a suggested edit?  When anyone edits an on hold post, it gets bumped back into our [review queues](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/review), where anyone with 500+ reputation can review and vote to reopen. Hope this helps clarify.

Comment: @jmort253 I am not sure what is unclear to you guys. This answer is really cool that I was looking.

Comment: I gave it an edit, based on what I think you were asking. (I think the problem was a mixture of just differences in language, as well as some grammatical issues and typos. Sometimes that's all it takes to clarify is simply fixing those problems). Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @jmort253 I did have to read the question several times before I thought I understood it enough to answer. I also assumed there was a language barrier causing the confusing wording of the question.  Glad it sounds like my answer hit the target.

Comment: @Emily - I think this is a fine artifact on our site now. If you, or Williams, want to know the ways you can help the Freelancing SE community be the best site on the Internet for freelancing problems, see http://meta.freelancing.stackexchange.com/q/194/64. Hope this helps!